# How to get/update picklist values using API in Postman?

Tags: json, okta-api, postman-collection-runner

I am querying Okta to return a multi-select (picklist) data type field and it returns "null"?
Below is the response and the role is a picklist

> ```
> "id": "00ger5zbmJQ9zyzkAY0x6",
> "lastUpdated": "2021-09-29T13:47:31.000Z",
> "priority": 0,
> "profile": {
>     "role": null,
>     "LocaleSidKey": null,
>     "eGroups": null,
>     "city": null,
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Schemas API to get the list of values. Please check https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/schemas/#get-user-schema

`GET /api/v1/meta/schemas/user/${typeId}`